# Laravel eager load function limit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, eager-loading

I have a working function, however, I'd like to limit the number of treatments, per consultant, that are returned.

**Working Example:**

```
Clinic::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->with('consultants.specialism', 'consultants.treatments')
            ->first();
```

**Proposed (but not working) example:**

```
Clinic::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->with('consultants.specialism')
            ->with(['consultants.treatments' => function ($query) {
                $query->take(3);
            }])
            ->first();
```

Unfortunately, the `take` or `limit` function, limits it to the total number of treatments returned.

> What I would like is to limit each consultant's treatments to a
>   maximum of 3, not the total.

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: `treatments` should return a collection of treatments, right? Then you want to get only first 3... So what's the problem? `->take(3)` does exactly that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607088/laravel-5-eager-loading-with-limit

Answer (score 6):

There is no native support for this in Laravel.

I created a package for it: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Use the `HasEagerLimit` trait in both the parent and the related model.

```php
class Consultant extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}

class Treatment extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

Then simply chain `->take(3)` call to your eager-load query (which seems you already do).

Comment: This is a great package Jonas, it's solved an issue I had and I think some of your others may help me too! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either fetch all related comments and truncate in php using something like [Collection::map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) or replace the eager loading with a [complex sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10516530/3784306)

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
Clinic::where('user_id', Auth::id()) 
->with(['consultants' => function ($query) { 
    $query
    ->with(['specialism','treatments'])
    ->take(3); 
}]) ->first();
```

I'm on my phone. So excuse my code formatting.

Comment: The query returned from the above (where the limit is used) is `select * from consultants where consultants.clinic_id in ('1') limit 3`. So that would, in essence, limit to only 3 consultants, not 3 treatments per consultant