# Laravel: how to eager load 2 models per model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eager-loading

I have a shop where people can leave a comment for a product. On the front page I would like to display the 2 best comments for each product. So I want to eager load the best 2 comments for each product when loading the products.

This is what I tried initially:

```
Product::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
  $query
  ->orderBy('points', 'desc')
  ->limit(2);
}])->get()
```

Instead of giving me the 2 best comments per product, it only gives me the 2 best comments of all the products.

Do you have any idea how to approach this? Thank you!

Comment: It caused by static method, you use. You are working, but you need Instance.

Comment: Please share datamodel of comments and products table.

Comment: refer this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044954/eloquent-eager-loading-constraint-limit

Comment: There is no simple way to do that in MySQL. So I don't think there is a way to avoid raw queries.

Comment: @Piterden what do you mean?

Comment: @macghriogair It's the most basic setup. Both have id, products have a title and comments a body and points.